# Failed to Load resource: the server responded with status 404 (not Found) during BUILD of a Hana DB Module

Tags: hana, sap-web-ide, web-ide, hana-xs

I am trying to create synonym in SAP WEB IDE. I created a new multi tenant project and also added a SAP HANA DATABASE MODULE under it. For creating a Synonym, I followed below steps:

1) I have created a user provided service (mydata-grantor).
2) Edited mta.yaml file to add the user provided service name in resources as below:

```
resources:
 - name: hdi_db
   parameters:
      config:
         schema: MYAPPDB
   properties:
      hdi-container-name: ${service-name}
   type: com[![enter image description here][1]][1].sap.xs.hdi-container
 - name: mydata-grantor
   type: org.cloudfoundry.existing-service
```

3) Created a .hdbgrants file to grant access and roles.
4) After completing above stpes, when I go to BUILD, I am getting and error that "*build of myapp/db failed*, check console logs for details. 
I am attaching the detailed error screenshot I am getting in console.

Comment: Can you attach the detailed log as mentioned please?

Comment: The log mentions "Failed to laod resources". Addition to that, a specific message is "Failed to resolve reference for provided property: 7f05a67-0fd9-4d40-a897-578fa884f02e-e9nrcbmdvpjvr2pc-DriverBasedForecasting#predictiveservice_datagrantor#hdi-container-name"

DriverBasedForecasting is name of the module. predictiveservice_datagrantor is the name of the user provided service.